# Does Google search results offset that of the Bing?

Tags: search-engine, bing

In a WPF application, I need to fetch results from various search engines and count the recurring and non-recurring words from the context (description & keywords) of the top 200 results. This task is to examine the understanding and the 'factor of popularity' of the given search-term in the society.

Given a set of search-engines, if we Google it first, do we need to Bing it?

Generally speaking:

- Does Google result-set offsets Bing's?
- Are they mutually exclusive?
- Can we expect mixed results on average?

Comment: Be careful: [You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Services.](https://accounts.google.com/TOS?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the results will be mixed. There will be pages that Google rates high but Bing rates low and vice versa. A site that is at the top of a Google search for a particular term is likely to also be highly positioned in Bing's search results for the same term, but it's not guaranteed as the two engines use different algorithms.

Comment: Thanks. I pulled results from both search engines' APIs and filtered the duplicate records.

Answer (score 1):

Each engine use different ranking system, so you can [and should] expect different results for Google and Bing queries.

For example, for the query euler: on [google](http://www.google.co.il/#hl=iw&q=euler&oq=euler&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=0l0l0l24733l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=d3c37cbb26c9f1e8&biw=1280&bih=697) the second result is Euler's formula [wiki article], while on [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=euler&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=eule&sc=8-2&sp=-1&sk=) it is the Project Euler page. [Note: search results are relevant for me - at february 21st, could change between users due to personalization].

Comment: Thanks for the insight. For the simple queries both work fine. But for the complex queries, perhaps a long sentence or a query with one or more phrases in quotation, it looks like Bing confuses the relevancy and it doesnt exactly highlight the query terms in search results.